# I saw a short-lived brightening and fading of a light in the sky. Was that a star imploding, exploding or going super-nova?

Tags: star, satellite

I was looking over the north-eastern skyline from a west coast location and notice something very bright for well over about 10 or 15 seconds, and then it faded completely. I didn't notice it before and I don't own any equipment that can see that far away but it looked like a star got really bright and then pulled into itself. Is it possible that I just watched a star go super-nova?

Comment: Which west coast? Here in Europe there were several reportings yesterday of a bright flare which apparently was the fuel particles of a Falcon 9 launched from California.

Comment: Was it stationary or did it move? If it moved it could be the ISS solar panels reflecting sunlight. Under certain circumstances it can be quite bright.

Comment: @jcaron Or one of the Starlink satellites. At least the OP didn't think it was a UFO, though...

Comment: It would probably help a lot to find out what it was you saw if you provided a more accurate location, direction, and time. The more accurate the better.

Comment: I find it amusing that, even in the context of discussing our _galaxy_, we tend to forget there are other countries in our own planet.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia I always know it's a USA citizen; no-one else does that online.

Comment: I just couldn't resist the joke: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly

Comment: Have you suddenly gained huge amounts of intelligence, maybe some telekinesis?  You might have an astrocytoma brain tumour.   Quite a *Phenomenon*.

Answer (score 43):

No. You likely saw a plane's landing lights, a satellite flare or a shooting star (at least something in the atmosphere or low earth orbit).

Two main reasons:

- A [supernova lasts for weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_curve#Supernovae) with only gradually decreasing
  brightness.
- Stars are so tiny that they don't have any visual spatial
  extent, even as supernova. See also [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/device-used-to-measure-stellar-radii) on stellar radii.

Comment: Also any visible star going supernovae would be world news. So if you don't see it on your local news sources, it wasn't a supernovae.

Comment: @Rob. Someone had to see it first for it to get to the news

Comment: @MadPhysicist That someone would be scientists who are scanning for events like this, not just some guy.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica not necessarily: "some guy" has been the first to discover a supernovae before: https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/417575-discovered-a-supernova-last-night/ & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmyjEI34BQA

Comment: Before the advent of automated searches in about the mid-ninety's, almost all the supernovae were discovered by amateurs. It was sort of a sport. (in which I participated.)  Total numbers were about a dozen per year.